# Highcharts yaxis labels not working

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with multiple yaxis, 3 data series. I'm trying to duplicate [this demo example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-multi-axes/)

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 1,...
```

with my own [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/help/2L9ah5nd/).

What I don't understand is the correlation between "opposite: true" declared in yAxis and "yAxis: 1, 2 ..." declared in series. I've tried countless variations to no avail. Am I missing something simple? Didn't quite understand the [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis)

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. There is no connection between the two. `opposite` just switches what side the labels are shown on. The indexing of the axis does not change based on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**  As per your comments I understood your actual issue. you need to place the series in same order as those yAxis were defined . see the [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/2L9ah5nd/8/)

yAxis: 0,1,2,3 means : in which order your yAxis are to be stacked/put in a order. If yAxis: 0 then it means it will be first series (fir yAxis) in your multiple yAxis series.

While opposite  just change the position of labels as stated by @Havor Strand in above comment.

```
yAxis :0 //in what order yAxis of Series
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/4b33pvc2/) for stack yAxis multiple seires
and see this [fiddle of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/2L9ah5nd/4/) , your points are so close,means data is too much but if you zomm your graph you can see that properly.

Comment: Still can't get it. Here's a new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/help/2L9ah5nd/) I've modified to match this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-multi-axes/). The Turbidirt range is correct, but I can't get the Pheophytin range to show up. Also, Chlorophyll seems to be using the Pheophytin data to establish the range. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? The above Highcharts example link is exactly what I want

Comment: I am surprised, I can see all the series in your fiddle.All 3 series are shown and having different data points. your fiddle has same chart as in example fiddle the only diff is you have area chat while example has bars

Comment: how does the yaxis order run, left to right? If there's 3 series, that means there's yaxis: 0, 1, 2?

Comment: it runs bottom to top

Comment: Do I have the order right in my jsfiddle? Could it be that the 2 series on right are sharing the same range?

Comment: Ohh , I got what u asking. You are talking about the label at right side , am I right?

Comment: yes, I have no idea why i can't duplicate [this demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-multi-axes/). I've tried countless variations to no avail.

Comment: which jsfiddle should i look at?

Comment: Very nice, thank you so much. A marine biologist and Cape Cod Bay also thank you. [Cape Cod Bay Monitoring Stations](http://www.capecodbay-monitor.org/). Making changes now

Comment: Welcome Always ,Cheers !!